# Is there infinite decreasing sequence of polynomials with natural coefficients?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, polynomials

We will say that polynomial $F$ is less than polynomial $G$ iff $\forall x$ (starting from certain point) $F(x) < G(x)$.

It seems like I want to use here fact that this set is well-founded. However, I don’t see any more or less elegant and simple ways to show it.

If you see any, I will be grateful for your assistance.

Comment: Have you figured out criteria on the degrees and coefficients of $F$ and $G$ that are equivalent to the property $F<G$?

Comment: If $P$ is a polynomial, you know that the sign of $P(x)$ for $x$ large is the same as the sign of the leading coefficient. Therefore, $F<G$ means that the leading coefficient of $G-F$ is positive. So, start by mapping the sequence to the sequence of their degrees. By the observation the sequence of degrees is non increasing. Since degrees are natural numbers the sequence of degrees is eventually constant. We consider the sequence starting from where the degrees become constant. This time we map the sequence to the sequence of their leading coefficients. This one is also non-increasing. ...

Comment: ... Therefore, since they are also natural numbers, it is eventually constant. So, we consider now the sequence of polynomials starting from when the degree and the leading coefficient become constant. This time we consider the sequence of  the next coefficient. The same argument shows that this one also is eventually constant. We continue in this way for smaller and smaller degrees. The is only finitely many steps to consider. Therefore, the sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: @plop That was long enough to need two full comments. Please don't answer questions in the comment section. The comment box even tells you this.

Comment: @Karl Yes, I did indeed. However, I had weird feeling about fact that for any positive degree of polynomial we have infinitely many polynomials that are less.

Comment: I removed my answer, since (thanks to @Sil) I discovered a lot of nasty complications. @plops approach is much cleaner.